# An error occurred while starting the kernel ipython console in spyder

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, spyder

1. I am using Spyder which I downloaded through Anaconda. I have been using it for several weeks but recently I have been getting a traceback error upon launching Spyder. It has happened 3 times now. The last two times I just reset Spyder to factory settings and everything was fine, but the issues returns. The only thing I've done that I can imagine is causing this issue is that I have changed my default path for the working directory used upon launch. Is this where the issue is? Is there some other way I should be doing this?
2. I have attempted to look for other posts about this issue, and although there are many posts about an error occurred while starting the kernel, the traceback seems to be different. Many of the solutions say to just delete some file, but don;t give much of an explanation of why there would be a file that is causing this issue, or truthfully I can not find that suggest file (for example: C:\Users\user\datetime.py.)

Any help would really be appreciated.

3. The error I receive:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Mathew\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", mod_spec)
File "C:\Users\Mathew\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Users\Mathew\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\console\__main__.py", line 11, in 
start.main()
File "C:\Users\Mathew\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\console\start.py", line 289, in main
import_spydercustomize()
File "C:\Users\Mathew\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\console\start.py", line 39, in import_spydercustomize
import spydercustomize
File "C:\Users\Mathew\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 17, in 
import pdb
File "C:\Users\Mathew\anaconda3\lib\pdb.py", line 73, in 
import cmd
File "C:\Users\Mathew\anaconda3\lib\cmd.py", line 50, in 
IDENTCHARS = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + '_'
AttributeError: module 'string' has no attribute 'ascii_letters'
```

Comment: This is pretty interesting. It probably has to do with the version of python you're using. Did you recently update python or spyder?

Comment: I updated spyder after this issue came up as it was recommended in a similar post, but that didn't fix the issue.

Comment: Is it possible that you don't have the python library string?

Comment: Try importing string in a test file and then passing `string.ascii_letters` =. It seems really weird to me because string is included in all installations of python. It could be that your version is corrupted or that the file that you have to delete handles string incorrectly.

Comment: I do have the string library. If I import string I get a description for "string.ascii_letters?". However, at the moment I am not able to recreate the issue in Spyder. It seems to come and go.

Comment: Try this code, if it doesn't work, then you should clean install python and then spyder. `import string
print(string.__file__)`

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) This problem happens because you have a file called `string,py` laying around (out of your Anaconda installation, I mean). You need to find it and rename or remove it.